# SwipeRefresh not working in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

SwipeRefresh not working in fragment.
My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pagerefresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" /></android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

My fragmnet code:

```
View drawer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress, container, false);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) drawer.findViewById(R.id.pagerefresh);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            getProgressData();
        }
    });
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_red_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);    adapter = new ProgressOrderListAdapter(orderLists, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return recyclerView;
```

getProgressData() function & it's more helpfull for you

```
private void getProgressData(){
    String token = SharedPreferencesManager.readPreferenceString("token", "D/N");
    JSONObject progressData = new JSONObject();
    try{
        progressData.put("token", token);
        JsonObjectRequest progressObject = new JsonObjectRequest(1, Common.OrderDetails + "progress", progressData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject progressResponse) {
                Log.d("Responseprogress", progressResponse.toString());
                try {
                    int status = progressResponse.getInt("status");
                    if(status == 1) {
                        progressOrderProgress(progressResponse);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Response", "PROGRESS ERROR");
            }
        });
        progressObject.setShouldCache(false);
        ServiceBellApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(progressObject);
    }
    catch (JSONException localJSONException){
        localJSONException.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}

private void progressOrderProgress(JSONObject progressResponse) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray result = progressResponse.getJSONArray("orderdata");
    for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++){
        OrderList orderListModule = new OrderList();
        JSONObject orderData = null;
        try {
            orderData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            orderListModule.setPackage_name(orderData.getString("name"));
            orderListModule.setOrderdate(orderData.getString("date"));
            orderListModule.setServicedate(orderData.getString("service"));
            orderListModule.setServicetime(orderData.getString("time"));
            orderListModule.setOrderid(orderData.getString("id"));
            orderListModule.setOrdstatus(orderData.getString("status"));
            orderListModule.setOrderamount(orderData.getInt("ramount"));
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        orderLists.add(orderListModule);
    }
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is my code.
I am not get any error in logcat, but it's not working.
Please help me friends

Comment: show `getProgressData()` function

Comment: That is my JsonObjectRequest function

Comment: show how you are setting adapter ...... show your complete code please.

Comment: good i need one more thing where is listview.setadapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mArrayList = new ArrayList<CabsETA>();

            mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSwipeLayout = true;                             
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                    getNear();
                }
            }
        );

    }
});

public void getNear() {
    latLongSevenKms();
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
}
```

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout">    

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#f5f5f5"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" /> 
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Use:

```java
LinearLayoutManager mm = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mm);
```

Comment: Not working.i put Log.d("refresh", "working"); in  mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {} no log dispaly

Comment: Did you set Layout to RecyclerView?

Comment: Add LayoutManager to Recycler View.

Comment: Already it's available in my code recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

Comment: You are Using Volley, Did you initialized RequestQueue ?

Comment: Add Log at OnRefresh and see OnRefresh is WOkring?

Answer (score 2):

Understand this basic flow what is see in your code you have done all thig just one thing is missed.

you made request get new data and then add it to `orderLists.add(orderListModule);` and then call  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` here is **issue** you should call here set adatpter with your new dataset instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
    listView.setAdapter();
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
      @Override
      public void onRefresh() {
            refreshContent();
          ...
  }

  // fake a network operation's delayed response 
  // this is just for demonstration, not real code!
  private void refreshContent(){ 
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getNewTweets());
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
  });
  }

  // get new cat names.
  // Normally this would be a call to a webservice using async task,
  // or a database operation

 private List<String> getNewCatNames() {
        List<String> newCatNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mCatNames.size(); i++) {
          int randomCatNameIndex = new Random().nextInt(mCatNames.size() - 1);
          newCatNames.add(mCatNames.get(randomCatNameIndex));
        }
        return newCatNames;
    }
```

**Update: in your code**

```
private void progressOrderProgress(JSONObject progressResponse) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray result = progressResponse.getJSONArray("orderdata");
    for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++){
        OrderList orderListModule = new OrderList();
        JSONObject orderData = null;
        try {
            orderData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            orderListModule.setPackage_name(orderData.getString("name"));
            orderListModule.setOrderdate(orderData.getString("date"));
            orderListModule.setServicedate(orderData.getString("service"));
            orderListModule.setServicetime(orderData.getString("time"));
            orderListModule.setOrderid(orderData.getString("id"));
            orderListModule.setOrdstatus(orderData.getString("status"));
            orderListModule.setOrderamount(orderData.getInt("ramount"));
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        orderLists.add(orderListModule);
    }
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    adapter = new ProgressOrderListAdapter(orderLists, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

[Full Demo Here.](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/)

Comment: Already i added recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); in onCreateView() function

Comment: adapter = new Adapter(.....); recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); after getting new values

Comment: my values display correctly but SwipeRefresh only not working